# How often should I change tom heads (batters and resonants)?

Tags: drums, maintenance

I have had my current tom heads on since February.

I only play on my kit for an average of once a week, and not long when I do.

Should I replace them all, batter and resonant heads?  I feel like I just now got them to tune well.

Comment: What's a resonant head? ;) .... not that I play wide open, but I also totally ignore those *for life* after I get them anywhere close to tuned. - But when you put the arm of the cheap ass snare stand through the bottom of the head because it doesn't clamp on... and there isn't another band letting you borrow theirs... then yeah.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've always considered that, unless you're one of those drummers who can beat heads into concave shapes, you change them if & when you want a different sound.

I've had the same two sets of heads [thin, clear ambassadors & thick double-skinned oil-rim 'pinstripes', for totally different vibes] for mine since the late 90s. I really don't play them any more, so they're never going to 'wear out' at this rate, but I've never noticed they really change over time.
I have a second, cocktail kit, which has non-standard head sizes I can't replace even if I wanted to. It was probably a cheap child's kit from perhaps the 70s to which I've added good peripheral hardware. As far as I'm aware the heads have never been changed.

Anecdotally, I can be the same with guitar strings, even though they change sound dramatically over a fairly short period.
Though I change my Rikki bass strings every 20 minutes because that's what a Rikki should sound like imo, my Strat I change reasonably frequently as soon as they lose that 'twang', but my Variax has had the same strings on for 15 years or more - they settled out to just how I like them & they haven't changed since. I've still got a spare set in the bag, just in case.

Comment: Yeah, guitar strings are really incomparable with drum heads. Sweat and dirt can and do affect the brightness. When I played guitar regularly (4 or 5 gigs per week, they'd get changed every gig, or at least every other gig.   Nowadays bass and guitar strings stay on a lot lot longer - neither instrument earns enough to warrant otherwise! Might change them if I'm recording, though. Drumskins - agree with you. Only change when absolutely necessary. Like hardly ever.

Comment: I used to change my Rikki strings once a week, Strat inside 2 months, always. The Variax regime came by accident. I made a whole album with it over a long period, about a year. As the strings dulled I realised I could pull a lot of the tone back with the modelling & I liked what it was doing, so kept the same set on. Eventually they just stopped 'evolving' & they've been on ever since. If my drum skins ever changed over time, it wasn't enough that I ever noticed. I don't break strings or dent heads, so status quo...

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin and Tim.  I am not sure why I got it into my head that they should be changed regularly.  Mine are not pitted and I will keep on keepin on.

Comment: Jason - there is every chance that technically they will lose a little of their 'zing' in the first month or two, however small the amount - but as you spend a fair amount of time tuning out all the uncontrolled 'zing' from drums anyway, this is likely a good thing. Either way, they reach an equilibrium you can then live with just about forever.

Comment: @JasonPSallinger - they *should* be changed regularly - like every ten years or so. Regularly, but not often...

Comment: "oil rim" pinstripes?

Comment: @Edward - their advertising now says *"Pinstripe® Clear drumheads have an overtone reducing agent"*. Back when I bought mine, they just called it 'oil' ;))

Comment: Oh, see I had never heard that referred to as "oil", I think maybe you got "oil" in your from [the old myth that 2 ply drumheads all had oil between the plies.](https://support.remo.com/hc/en-us/articles/360028358392-Is-There-Oil-In-Remo-Drumheads-Prismatic-Visual-Effect)   Remo says there is no oil in their heads.

Comment: @Edward - you may indeed be right. It actually says nothing but Weatherking Pin Stripe on them. I guess it was just a common misnomer at the time. I can't say I've ever researched it, nor have I shopped for new heads in 15 years or more. [I never really liked them, they were too mono-tone & dull for me, with less overtone control than I like, so I put regular clear Ambassadors back on all that time ago & these sit gathering dust in a bag;)

Comment: I'm "one of those drummers". They *last* for six months. They were *good* for the first one. Everyone sounds good on a set of fresh skins; you can do one handed rolls with all that rebound. - As with carpentry, *mastery* is making do with less than ideal tools and materials; I wasn't going to spend $200 a month on Aquarian skins (which *look* like there's oil in there) when I needed that money for not-broken sticks and cymbals, or none of this matters anyway.

Answer (score 3):

My kit has had the same heads for ages. As long as you don't beat the hell out of them, they will last for ages. Particularly in a dry, constant environment.

If the beaters look like they're pitted, maybe due to being played really hard (why do that?) then it's probably time for a change, but otherwise, playing even an hour or so every day, plus a gig a week, if they're staying in tune, let sleeping dogs lie! Resonant heads the same, except they don't get battered - obviously!

EDIT: having had a chance to chat with a couple of pro drummers, a point came up I'd not considered. Not particularly relevant to rock type drummers, but relevant to jazzers in particular. And we don't know what OP is!

Using *brushes* will mean the beater heads will literally get worn out, and a pro could get through a head in 6 months. The brushes will wear the coating off the batter head due to their movement - quite different from sticks. Obviously, as stated previously, the resonant heads won't be affected.

This will really be focussed on the *snare*, and OP asks about *toms*. Toms will probably get used less tan snare anyhow, but still worth a mention.